# How to deprecate a method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, deprecated

We have our library we ship to our customers, and I'd like to mark some methods as "deprecated" because we changed them (like Apple does in the iPhone SDK).

I've seen the `__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED` pre-processor macro, which is mapped to `__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL`, which is mapped to `__attribute__((deprecated))`...

Well i'm a bit confused with this stuff!

Anybody knows something about that ?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

`__attribute__((deprecated))` is the [gcc way](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bdeprecated_007d-function-attribute-3214) (also [supported in clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#deprecated-gnu-deprecated)) of marking a function / method as deprecated. When one is marked as "deprecated", a warning will be produced whenever anyone calls it.

The syntax for normal functions would be

```
__attribute__((deprecated))
void f(...) {
  ...
}

// gcc 4.5+ / clang
__attribute__((deprecated("g has been deprecated please use g2 instead")))
void g(...) {
  ...
}
```

and that of Objective-C methods would be

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject { ... }
-(void)f:(id)x __attribute__((deprecated));
...
@end
```

You can also mark the whole class as deprecated with

```
__attribute__((deprecated))
@interface DeprecatedClass : NSObject { ... }
...
@end
```

---

Apple also provides the `<AvailabilityMacros.h>` header which provides the DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE and DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(msg) macros that expand to the above attributes, or nothing if the compiler doesn't support attributes. Note that this header doesn't exist outside of OS X / iOS.

---

Side note, if you are using Swift you use the [`@available` attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) to deprecate an item, e.g.

```
@available(*, deprecated=2.0, message="no longer needed")
func f() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer, I'm pretty sure it will help, I searched for a while before asking :)

Comment: I just have another question : is it possible to add a message like "Use method XXX instead" ?

Comment: @Julien: Yes: `__attribute((deprecated(use method XXX instead)))`. But this syntax is available only starting from gcc 4.5, and the version shipped with Xcode is 4.2...

Comment: If I add deprecated attribute only to method declaration the compiler says "Attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match". Do I need to add smth to method implementation?

Comment: @BorutTomazin: Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @KennyTM: I just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100356/how-to-properly-deprecate-a-method-in-xcode-4

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. It's not how Apple does it, and it's way uglier than `DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE`

Comment: It's fairly unlikely that people needing this answer will still be using an Xcode that compiles with gcc as it was removed [as of Xcode 5](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469410-OS-X-GCC-Clang-and-Cython-in-10-9-Mavericks). Does this directive work with the clang compiler? … I'd suggest the [macro alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24611423/2547229).

Answer (score 76):

You can also use more readable **define** `DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE`

It defined in `usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h`:

```
#define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
#define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(msg) __attribute((deprecated((msg))))
```

**Objective-C** methods example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject { ... }
-(void)foo:(id)x DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;

// If you want to specify deprecated message:
-(void)bar:(id)x DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Use baz: method instead.");
...
@end
```

You can also mark the whole class as deprecated:

```
DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE
@interface DeprecatedClass : NSObject { ... }
...
@end
```

Comment: This is the way Apple does it in iOS classes too. Probably the better method.

Comment: It's definitely the better method. Pity it's not the selected answer, or the higher voted answer.

Comment: how can i use `DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE` to mark a class as deprecated with message (like UIAlertView)

Comment: Is there the concept of 'renamed' similar to the available attributes in Swift?

Answer (score 18):

### Swift 5.0

Deprecate any method/class/struct/protocols using `@available`

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Parse your data by hand instead")
func parseData() { }

@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "loadData")
func fetchData() { }

@available(swift, obsoleted: 4.1, renamed: "attemptConnection")
func testConnection() { }

@available(swift, deprecated: 4.0, obsoleted: 5.0, message: "This will be removed in v5.0; please migrate to a different API.")
```

Possible params:

- introduced
- deprecated
- obsoleted
- message
- renamed

For more info see apple doc: [Attributes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++14 in your xcode project, you may also use the `[[deprecated]]` or `[[deprecated("reason")]]` attribute that is now part of the language.

see documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes

Answer (score 0):

### - FOR SWIFT CODE:

Put this right above the method:
`@available(*, deprecated: <#Version#>, message: <#Message#>)`

example:

```
@available(*, deprecated: 11, message: "Use color assets instead")
public struct ColorPaletteItemResource: ColorPaletteItemResourceType {
    ...
}
```