# How to properly deprecate a method in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, methods, deprecated

I've just looked over the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924285/how-to-deprecate-a-method-in-xcode) but didn't help. When I add a deprecated attribute only to method declaration than the compiler says `Attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match`. Do I need to add smth to method implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add the attribute to the declaration:

```
@interface Blah
- (void)method __attribute__((deprecated));
@end
```

Provided your includes are correct for the translation, this should work fine. Perhaps you have added the attribute to the *definition*, not the *declaration*? Otherwise, a demonstration (code sample) would help.

**Update**

Although the above approach works for typical messages, it appears clang gets confused with `IBAction`s.

With clang, `ibaction` attributes are implicitly inserted (for what was formerly a `typedef`).

When the attribute is specified in the declaration only, the preprocessor output is as follows:

```
// preprocessed declaration
- (void)__attribute__((ibaction))setSomething:(id)sender __attribute__((noreturn));
// preprocessed implementation
- (void)__attribute__((ibaction))setSomething:(id)sender
...
```

So, it appears the compiler is just confused by this hidden decoration, and you must also add the attribute to the implementation/definition to suppress the warning when the method is an `IBAction`.

Comment: - (IBAction)showTag __attribute__((deprecated));
I get this: Attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match.

Comment: @BorutTomazin it's apparently specific to `IBActions` -- see update.

Comment: Yep, you are right. It works for non-ibaction methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the deprecated attribute on both the declaration and the implementation of the method, at least in Xcode 4.3.2 with clang.

Comment: Shrug.  I guess they implemented it differently in clang than in gcc.