# How can I have Xcode warn other developers of methods not supported by there build target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am upgrading an open source project that I maintain to use the latest iOS 8 SDKs. To do this, I will be introducing some new methods that will not work at all with iOS 7 and previous operating systems. I would like to specify the @interface in such a way that someone implementing this library will see a warning in Xcode if they try to use one of these methods with a build target below iOS 8.

For example, if they had a build target of iOS 7, and tried to call mySpecialiOS8Method, they should get a warning flag on that line of code saying "Warning: mySpecialiOS8Method is not available for iOS 7, use crappieriOS7CompatibleMethod instead to maintain compatibility". These warnings should not be visible with an iOS 8 build target.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Mark it as being available as of iOS 8. Look at many of the Apple header files for how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

Using [__ attribute__](http://nshipster.com/__attribute__/), you can warn when deprecated methods are used.

Here is a SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21246294/1835803) which could also help you.

Comment: I am not looking to deprecate methods, but rather the opposite. I have methods that are only available on iOS 8, but library still works on iOS 7 and 8 with the older methods. I want to disable using the iOS 8 only methods if the build target is less than iOS 8.