# adding comment to deprecated method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, deprecated

I have a couple of methods that I want to deprecate.

I do this with the following:

```
+(void)myMethod:(NSString*)abc __deprecated;
```

This works, but how do I add a message? Something like "use methody xyz instead"...

Thanks

Comment: what about adding headerdoc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924285/how-to-deprecate-a-method-in-xcode according to the 3rd comment on the answer you use `__attribute((deprecated(use x method)))`

Comment: Tried that but I get an error at the space after "use". Xcode says "Expected )"

Comment: My bad, I should have followed up on the answer rather than just linking it, in the clang language extensions guide (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#messages-on-deprecated-and-unavailable-attributes) it says the message must be inside `""`.

Comment: It's that simple huh *head:desk* :) make this into an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Nicholas Smith mentioned in the comments. The solution is:

```
__attribute((deprecated("use x method")))
```

if you want you can also use the less convoluted:

```
__deprecated_msg("use x method")
```

Comment: Works just fine for C as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would tend to use this:

```
__deprecated_msg("use method x instead")
```

rather than:

```
__attribute((deprecated("use method x instead")))
```

They're really the same under the hood, but first one is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

### - FOR SWIFT CODE:

Put this right above the method:
`@available(*, deprecated: <#Version#>, message: <#Message#>)`

example:

```
@available(*, deprecated: 11, message: "Use color assets instead")
public struct ColorPaletteItemResource: ColorPaletteItemResourceType {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a documentation generator: Doxygen, Headerdoc, etc.

I recommend you [Appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/). It is easy to use, very well documented and markdown style enabled.

Comment: That'd be useful for generating class documentation, I think the question is more for compile time warnings.