# How to manually deprecate members

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, c-preprocessor, deprecated

Unlike Objective-C, Swift has no preprocessor, so is there still a way to manually deprecate members of a class?

I am looking for something similar to this:

```
-(id)method __deprecated;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deprecate a method in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924285/how-to-deprecate-a-method-in-xcode)

Answer (score 304, accepted):

You can use the Available tag, for example :

```
@available(*, deprecated)
func myFunc() { 
    // ...
}
```

Where * is the platform (iOS, iOSApplicationExtension, macOS, watchOS, tvOS, * for all, etc.).

You can also specify the version of the platform from which it was `introduced`, `deprecated`, `obsoleted`, `renamed`, and a `message` :

```
@available(iOS, deprecated:6.0)
func myFunc() { 
    // calling this function is deprecated on iOS6+
}

Or

@available(iOS, deprecated: 6.0, obsoleted: 7.0, message: "Because !")
func myFunc() {
    // deprecated from iOS6, and obsoleted after iOS7, the message "Because !" is displayed in XCode warnings
}
```

If your project targets multiple platforms, you can use several tags like so :

```
@available(tvOS, deprecated:9.0.1)
@available(iOS, deprecated:9.1)
@available(macOS, unavailable, message: "Unavailable on macOS")
func myFunc() {
    // ...
}
```

More details in the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html).

Comment: In Swift 3, the `=`s are replaced with `:`s.

Comment: `*, deprecated: 10.0` will deprecate it for `iOS 10`, `tvOS 10` etc, I guess we should not combine `*` with a version number? Any ideas on how to do it better?

Comment: @fabb It is the version of the app, not iOS

Comment: That is not true. From the docs you linked: "version of the specified platform"

Comment: @fabb my bad, it is the iOS version, you can combine multiple tags like : `@available(iOS, deprecated:9.1) @available(tvOS, deprecated:9.0.1)`

Comment: Exactly, coming back to my original point: `@available(*, deprecated: 10.0)` therefore is a very bad idea should the code not only run on iOS

Comment: Works before a `class` too

Answer (score 80):

Starting **Swift 3** and **Swift 4**, the version number is optional. You can now simply type:

```
@available(*, deprecated)
func foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you want a message go along with it:

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "no longer available ...")
func foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For Swift 2.3, version number is optional, too.

Comment: For Swift 2.3, the syntax seems to be `@available(*, deprecated, message = "no longer available ...")` when including a message.

Comment: @Daniel, that's weird that Apple changes part of it and not the rest and calling it 2.3. Sign, I will update the answer again, thanks for the note!

Answer (score 6):

You can use this to auto-fix you entrys with your new func

```
@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "myNewFunc")
func myOldFunc() {
   // ...
}

func myNewFunc() {
   // ...
}
```

Instead of * you can use swift , for the swift Version number.

Deprecated functions generate warnings but can still be called. (Warning)

Obsolete functions stop it from being called entirely. (Error)

```
@available(swift, deprecated: 4.0, obsoleted: 4.2, message: "This will be removed in v4.2, please migrate to ...")
```

or use other Options like iOS, macOS, watchOS, tvOS ...

Answer (score 3):

**iOS deprecate**

```
@available(iOS, deprecated:7.0, obsoleted: <ObsoletedVersion>, renamed: "myFuncNew", message: "Please use new method - myFuncNew()")
func myFuncOld() {
    //logic
}
```

If `deployment target`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63671561/4770877) == `9.0` and

- `<ObsoletedVersion>` == `10.0` - `warning`

  [image]
- `<ObsoletedVersion>` == `8.0` - `compile error`

  [image]

Comment: In case of "obsolete" option, cannot use it. According to this, the option is not implemented. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8168

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5.0

Deprecate any method/class/struct/protocols using `@available`

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Parse your data by hand instead")
func parseData() { }

@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "loadData")
func fetchData() { }

@available(swift, obsoleted: 4.1, renamed: "attemptConnection")
func testConnection() { }

@available(swift, deprecated: 4.0, obsoleted: 5.0, message: "This will be removed in v5.0; please migrate to a different API.")
```

Possible params:

- introduced
- deprecated
- obsoleted
- message
- renamed

For more info see apple doc: [Attributes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html)

Original Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56379453/4061501

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to deprecate the default init method from a specific version so I have done the following:

```
// Old Method to be deprecated
@available(*, unavailable, message: "This method has been deprecated from version 2.0.0. Please use new init method as init(param1:param2:)")
@objc public override init() {
    super.init()
    
    /**
     * This fatalError has been thrown if anyone is using this function in Objective-C and initializes this with the following syntax.
     * MyClass *classObj = [MyClass new];
     */
    fatalError("This method has been deprecated from version 2.0.0. Please use new init method as init(param1:param2:)")
}

// New init method
@objc public required init(param1: String, param2: String) {
    super.init()
    
    // New init method logic goes here.
}
```