# WKWebView causing Bad Syntax before iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a project with iOS8.0+ support. I am using a WKWebView to load payment page; the page is working fine on iOS 11.0+ but it is showing bad Syntax for iOS 9 and 10. The info inside the loaded request are fetched from the server so there is no possibility that the error is in the request information.

Can anyone help me with issues known about WKWebView or any other similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in WKWebView before iOS 11 that requires programmatic creation of the WKWebView instance (so you cannot do it from Storyboard).

A discussion & resolution of this issue can be found here:
[Xcode 9 GM - WKWebView NSCoding support was broken in previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions)