# Html navbar : fix WKWebview compatibility with IOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, ios11, wkwebview

I need to create a Webview in my application.

As you may know, `WKWebview` have been fixed in IOS 11 and his initialization is storyboard is impossible if you want your application to be compatible with lower versions of IOS (more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions/47069884)). The only way to use it is to init it in the code :

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: currentView.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)
    self.webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    currentView.addSubview(self.webView)
}
```

(`currentView` is a view in the storyboard)

The problem is that I have now a display bug in IOS 10.3 that is not in IOS 11. The navbar of the website I want to put in the `WKWebView` isn't fixed on the top of the screen when you scroll down, as you can see in this photo :

[image: bug on left and correct version on right]

(bug on left and correct version on right)

Is there any way to fix the navbar?

Comment: The html navbar is a `navbar-fixed-top` from bootstrap 3 if it can be of any help