# WKWebView in StoryBoard or Programmatically (Swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift, web, wkwebview

If I add a WKWebView in the storyboard, Xcode throws an error saying that it is not supported for iOS 10 and below. However, if I add it programmatically, everything works fine. Does that mean if I add it in the storyboard, my app will only work with iOS11 when shipped out to the App Store?

Comment: Please check your deployment target.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 GM - WKWebView NSCoding support was broken in previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions)

Answer (score 4):

You can't make build if your **deployment target is below iOS 11** and `WKWebview` added via Storyboard. But You can add WKWebview programmatically.

WKWebview available since iOS 9. Now only they provide the option to add WKWebview via Storyboard. But I don't know why Apple has this restriction.