# Using WKWebView in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I was trying to use WKWebView in iOS 10 and came across an error related to NSCoding.

While searching for it, I came across [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions) and hence decided to implement it programmatically.

I added a view controller in the storyboard and I am then adding WKUIDelegate to my controller. However even after that, I am not seeing the web page show up on my screen.

My view controller acting as web view code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var articleURL: URL?
    @IBOutlet var webViewContainer: UIView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let customFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: self.webViewContainer.frame.size.height))
        self.webView = WKWebView (frame: customFrame , configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        guard let url = articleURL else {
            return
        }
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

I segue into this controller from my previous controller. Code for segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "webPage" {
        let controller = (segue.destination as? WebViewController)!
        controller.articleURL = movieReview?.articleURL
    }
}
```

Storyboard image:

[image]

I am actually navigating to the view, but it's blank. When I debug, my code does execute 'webView.load(myRequest)', but am not seeing anything on the screen.

What else am I missing?

Comment: can you check your delegate method execute on request complete or Fail ?

Comment: your code looks correct, i think you need to check your delegate methods, otherwise you can load www.google.com page for testing purpose for 100% success rate

Comment: I tried loading google and it worked fine. I then tried my url and since it has http and not https it's not loading. I guess I will have to update the url string to https. Thanks!

Comment: thats great you found solution, then ignore my answer :) i faced same issue on friday and issue was in programatically constraint. have a good day

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your **webViewContainer** view is connected to in your storyboard viewcontroller. if its already connected and constraint setup correctly on it. then make constraint on webview like this way.Add constraint from **self.view** not from **self.webview** , after adding to container webview is child of your parent view so it is best to add constraint from self.view to your webView. Hope so this will work.

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webViewContainer, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webViewContainer, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webViewContainer, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.webViewContainer, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```