# How to use webview in iOS 10 or lower versions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, webview

Currently I'm using WKWebView, but it is supporting from iOS 11 onwards. So if i want to use web view in iOS 10 or lower versions what is the solution. My app is already in App Store with UIWebView. Just now I changed from UIWebView to WKWebView. But it's not supporting before iOS 11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 9 GM - WKWebView NSCoding support was broken in previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I'm using WKWebView, but it is supporting from iOS 11 onwards. So if i want to use web view in iOS 10 or lower versions what is the solution.

This is not true.  [`WKWebView` is supported from iOS 8 onwards](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview).

Comment: but I got error

Comment: Post the error.  Never say *"I got error"* without posting the error.

Comment: WKWebView before iOS11.0 (WKWebView NSCoding support was broken in previous versions)

Comment: `NSCoding` is how storyboards and nibs are deserialised.  You need to create `WKWebView` programmatically.  See this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions

Comment: thank you. For lower version we need to create WKWebView programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

`WKWebView` is supported from iOS 8 onwards. So I don't think you will have any problem with your app.

You can refer the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) for clarification.