# iOS pdf digital signature not shown in UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, annotations, uiwebview, digital-signature

I'm displaying a pdf file in a UIWebView (need support for iOS 10), the file is a signed document, so it has sign annotations (boxes with digital signature) which are not shown. If I save the file and open with Acrobat then I can see them, so they are present but not visible in the UIWebView. The same problem on Android was solved by setting .enableAnnotationRendering(true) to the object of the library in use.
Any hint on how to fix it or about any free library that could solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using WKWebView? It is supported back to iOS 8.0 and is required moving forward. Apple will no longer accept submissions for apps that include UIWebView

Comment: For this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221577/xcode-9-gm-wkwebview-nscoding-support-was-broken-in-previous-versions. I could try to add it manually from code and see if WKWebView solves the rendering issue.