# Updating testing iPhone 6S to 11.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I saw that iOS 11.1 has been officially rolled out but I still see "deployment target" in Xcode to support up to iOS 11.

Does that mean that if I update it to iOS 11.1 I won't be able to test my apps on it? Is that what It means or I interpret it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So some quick information on deployment targets:

Lets say you have set minimum deployment target to iOS 9. This means your application is compatible for iOS 9 and **above** devices.

The application won't run on below 9.0 devices but can run on any iOS version greater than iOS 9.0. [Article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278392/what-does-deployment-target-mean)

I tested this and it DID NOT work unfortunately. I was running the latest Xcode and just updated my phone. You should wait until Xcode officially supports iOS 11.1+ before upgrading.

Comment: Well, I remember I've updated my phone like 3 weeks ago, it was a beta version (I think 11.3) and I couldn't test the app at all. I dont remember what the exact message was, but it didn't allowed me to test it before I rolled back to 11. But that version was beta, maybe that was the reason? It was very odd

Comment: I reached out to Apple Feedback in regards to this as well, haven't heard back yet. I wasn't able to build my app after upgrading to the latest Xcode beta, and the latest iOS beta. I can test this in a few hours if you can wait haha.

Comment: I can totally wait! Considering that I erased my entire phone data by accident, I can wait hahaha I would very much appreciate if you share what you found out!

Comment: @Dani you can’t build to 11.1+ with the current version of Xcode. Keep an eye out for an update where they support iOS 11.1+

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! It's kinda odd and stupid when you think about it, but nothing we can do about it. Thank you!