# Select iOS version to build for

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer

I am rather new to Swift and iOS programming. Currently I'm working on an app that should work with iOS 11.0 and up. As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278392/what-does-deployment-target-mean/41278576), selecting "Deployment Target -> iOS Deployment Target 11.0" in XCode will do the trick, I can also see that it changes IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 11.0. So far so good.

Now, on this [Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/), it says

> App updates must be built with the iOS 13 SDK starting June 30, 2020.

So my (most probably simple) question is: how can I make sure that this is the case for my app? Where in XCode (or alternatively AppCode) can I see/set what iOS SDK I'm building with? I'm using the latest (as per 15.07.2020) version of XCode. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing **iOS Deployment Target** with **iOS SDK Version**.

The **iOS Deployment Target** is the minimum iOS version your users must meet in order for them to install and run your app. i.e. an iOS 11.0 deployment target won't let **< iOS 11.0** (10.x, 9.x, 8.x, etc...) users install your app.

---

The **iOS SDK Version** on the other hand is the version of the SDK included in your Xcode. To check what SDK you are building, run in your terminal:

> xcodebuild -showsdks

I'm using Xcode 11.5, and that command gives me:

```
iOS SDKs:
    iOS 13.5                        -sdk iphoneos13.5

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 13.5            -sdk iphonesimulator13.5

macOS SDKs:
    DriverKit 19.0                  -sdk driverkit.macosx19.0
    macOS 10.15                     -sdk macosx10.15

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 13.4                       -sdk appletvos13.4

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 13.4           -sdk appletvsimulator13.4

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 6.2                     -sdk watchos6.2

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 6.2         -sdk watchsimulator6.2
```

---

Or just know that you just need an **Xcode 11.x** for iOS 13 SDK.

Comment: Ah, I understand. That explains why I wasn't able to find any setting or variable for the SDK...