# What is the Swift equivalent of NS_UNAVAILABLE?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Objective-C we can mark certain methods as NS_UNAVAILABLE meaning we will get a compiler level error if there is an attempt to call them. This can be useful when a sub class wants to reduce the scope of the api of the superclass it inherits from. For example a new UIView subclass might want to enforce that it has to be created via a nib and thus might mark initWithFrame as unavailable.

Swift has the @available marker but is there a simple way to mark a method is unavailable similar to NS_UNAVAILABLE in Objective-C?

Comment: I haven't seen other way around. I think we have to use something like @available(*, unavailable, message: "Err msg")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually deprecate members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405133/how-to-manually-deprecate-members)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `@available` by marking the function as `@available(*, unavailable)`.

You can read up on [it here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) under **Declaration Attributes**.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without having to define init(frame:)? For example, in my class, I don't want anyone to call init(). My class uses init(), but it wants init to be private. So I can do:
private override init() {
   super.init()
}
But I really want to do this like NS_UNAVAILABLE, without having to provide an implementation for init().