# Mark a class in Objective-C as deprecated at a particular iOS version and include a message

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated, deprecation-warning

How do I mark a class in Objective-C as deprecated at a particular iOS version and include a message?

I've seen that there's `NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 11_0)` but I can figure out where to put it to use it on a class and how to add a message to it that will be output as a warning if someone tries to use it.

Comment: Check answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56379453/4061501

Answer (score 4):

Found it:

`NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 11_0, "Stop using this class")`